# action controller strong params with value that can be either scalar OR array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

I have an endpoint that receives data in such a way:

```
{:stuff => [ { :name => 'item_1', :value => [ { :arcade_game => "Dragon's Lair", :manufacturer => "Cinematronics", } ] }, { :name => 'item_2', :value => 'something else' } ] }
```

Because there are some values that are scalar, and some are arrays, this becomes problematic because:

```
params.permit(:stuff => [:name, :value]).require(:stuff)
```

will give me:

```
=> [{"name"=>"item_1"}, {"name"=>"item_2", "value"=>"something else"}]
```

and

```
params.permit(:stuff => [:name, :value => [:manufacturer, :arcade_game]]).require(:stuff)
```

will give me:

```
=> [{"name"=>"item_1", "value"=>[{"manufacturer"=>"Cinematronics", "arcade_game"=>"Dragon's Lair"}]}, {"name"=>"item_2", "value"=>nil}]
```

...

So the only way I can figure out to get around this problem is to do something that looks and feels beyond extremely terrible:

```
params.permit(:stuff => [:name, :value]).tap do |whitelisted|
    params[:stuff].each_with_index do |stuff, index| 
        whitelisted[:stuff][index][:value] = params[:stuff][index].permit(:name, :value => [:arcade_game, :manufacturer]).require(:value) if params[:stuff][index][:value].is_a?(Array)
    end
end}.require(:stuff)
```

ewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

How in the world are you supposed to handle dynamic values like this???

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.
I think it will allow both scalar and array type of values.

```
params.permit(:stuff => []).require(:stuff)
```